# QGIS 3 Dragging layer in table of content with keyboard

Tags: qgis, table-of-contents

[Sometimes](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40601) it is hard to drag a layer with a mouse.

Is there a way to drag a layer (сhange its position relative to other layers) in a QGIS 3 table of content using only the keyboard?